# IDEA + Grunt - how to Live Edit JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, gruntjs, liveedit

Having an AngularJS app of basic structure - components, providers, services.. many separated .js files.. I use a grunt taks to compile them into single .js file eg: `application.js?v${build}`

To save time, I use IDEA plugin "Live Edit", it reflects all changes in .html real-time to browser.

All connected by JavaScript Debug config via "JetBrains IDE Support" plugin with Chromium web browser. All those work fine.

Now the problem: **I cannot live reload changes in angular/JS**. After every change I have to manually run grunt task to compile angular to single js and hit F5 in browser. (I know it is not a big deal, but image doing that 1000 in a day :) Any help appreciated!

PS: I can debug the JS, debugger stop correctly on breakpoints set in IDEA IDE.

Answer (score 0):

How about grunt plugins for watching changes and using [browser sync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/grunt/) for reload? There are also other approaches like using [yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) for creating structures and serving them with grunt automatically.